How can I manipulate bitmap images in Blazor hybrid?
I'm working on a Blazor Hybrid app and I need to open a bitmap image from a location on the hard drive with a file picker. Make some changes like resize and then save it to another location on the hard drive.
I tried to use System.Drawing but it is not working in Blazor Hybrid.
I couldn't find a way on how to do this.
Is Microsoft.Maui.Graphics working with Balzor hybrid?
